# Advice requested for a question closed as a duplicate

Tags: discussion

Earlier today I asked a question [*"How to find out what version of a package is in an apt repository?"*](https://askubuntu.com/q/1376114/197753) which was closed as a duplicate of [*"How to install Google Chrome"*](https://askubuntu.com/q/510056/197753).

I feel like me adding details and context to my question worked against me here, and that the mention of "*installing Google Chrome*" jumped out and caused a quick closure as a duplicate. But actually *I don't care (currently) about how to install Google Chrome* specifically. I want to know how I can effectively browse through the contents of  azure.archive.ubuntu.com, as a skill that seems useful on its own.

I even tried to clarify that at the end of my question, the "teach me how to fish" part, but now the dupe-hammer has given me a fish and told me to move on after all. And now I still don't know how to dig through azure.archive.ubuntu.com.

Any recommendations for what to do? Should I vote to reopen with my explanation? Should I write a new, more dedicated question that is more succinct (and not mention google-chrome at all)? Should I find my help outside of askubuntu.com? Your advice, please.

Comment: I can't see how this would be a dupe of the linked post, nor how to assume it is a dupe, apart from the words "Google Chrome". voted to reopen. Dupes in general is the subject where most accidents happen. Think we would benefit from a clear definition of the subject. Everyone seems to have his or her own idea.

Comment: Cheers, thx for the sanity check. I've done a bunch of queues on other Stack Exchange sites and can imagine a mixup happening. Glad I asked here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've reopened the post and removed the dupe link.